# Is a standard-compliant (RFC 7230) HTTP-server allowed to respond with only 400 Bad Request?

Tags: http, language-lawyer, standards, bad-request, rfc

A question that arose while reading the [*RFC 7230: Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Message Syntax and Routing*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) was "what is the simplest possible server that this would be compliant with this standard". Searching for "MUST" in the document, it seems to me that the only responses a server *has* to return is a 400-error, in the case of the request being malformed:

> A
> server MUST reject any received request message that contains
> whitespace between a header field-name and colon with a response code
> of 400 (Bad Request).

(3.2.4. Field Parsing)

> If a Transfer-Encoding header field
> is present in a request and the chunked transfer coding is not
> the final encoding, the message body length cannot be determined
> reliably; the server MUST respond with the 400 (Bad Request)
> status code and then close the connection.

(3.3.3. Message Body Length .3)

> If this is a
> request message, the server MUST respond with a 400 (Bad Request)
> status code and then close the connection.

(3.3.3. Message Body Length .4)

among others.

There are some cases where the standard dictates that the server MUST return a certain status code, but they all seem to be made optional by some stronger clause, for example:

> If a server receives both an Upgrade and an Expect header field with
> the "100-continue" expectation (Section 5.1.1 of [RFC7231]), the
> server MUST send a 100 (Continue) response before sending a 101
> (Switching Protocols) response.

(6.7 Upgrade)

being made optional by

> A server MAY ignore a received Upgrade
> header field if it wishes to continue using the current protocol on
> that connection.  Upgrade cannot be used to insist on a protocol
> change.

(6.7 Upgrade)

All of this leads me to believe that a 400-only server is technically allowed by the standard.

This does seem rather odd to me, I thought a 400-header meant that the request itself was malformed in some way and that a server had to respond with some other error iff the request was well-formed but invalid in some other way.

Have I missed something in the standard, or some other relevant standard, or is a 400-only server allowed?

(As a side note, section 2.6 states

> A server can send a 505
> (HTTP Version Not Supported) response if it wishes, for any reason,
> to refuse service of the client's major protocol version.

which leads me to believe a 505-only server would actually be allowed, although quite boring)

Comment: Note that RFC 7230 is just one of the documents defining HTTP 1.1. See [RFC 7231](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231), for example.